# Is it possible to Data Compare without doing a Data Synchronization in Navicat?

Tags: mysql, navicat

Does anyone know if Navicat allows you to do a Data Compare without actually performing the Synchronization?  Been searching high and low to find something that works well for comparing the data across 2 databases on OS X.

I would use Mysql-utilities tool `mysqldbcompare` which creates reports in a real nice format, but can't seem to get passed some bugs with it.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Just Realized there's a `Preview` button in the `Data Synchronization` Window...  This will run the comparison with trying to synchronize.  And it will still output the SQL that will actually make the synchronization.